# Horizontal gene transfer from humans

Tags: genetics, dna, human-genetics, horizontal-gene-transfer

It is known that some viruses embed themselves in the human genome. Is there a mechanism by which human genes can be transferred to other animals or plants by means of viruses shuttling them from humans to other organisms?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Horizontal gene transfer ([HGT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_gene_transfer)) can happen in [both ways](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3068243/), from prokaryotes to eukaryotes and vice versa. So far less attension is given to from eukaryotes to prokaryotes HGT. It has played very important role in [eukaryotic evolution](http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v9/n8/full/nrg2386.html) also. Following figure from ([Patrick and Palmer 2008](http://www.nature.com/nrg/journal/v9/n8/full/nrg2386.html)) shows some potential cases in eukaryotic phylogeny.
[image]

You can find many such examples from above reference. Coming to human part, there are few cases like From Humans to [Plasmodium vivax](http://precedings.nature.com/documents/5690/version/1) and From human to [Neisseria gonorrhoeae](http://mbio.asm.org/content/2/1/e00005-11.full) , where researchers have shown evidence of HGT from humans to prokaryotes. Unfortunately , there is very little on mechanism by which they transfer. It is matter of speculation right now as these studies are controversial.

Comment: Is this only about organelle genes?

Comment: No, even nuclear genes undergo HGT as mentioned in reference articles. You can check that paper, it has few examples.